# laravel 8 symbolic link for image not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, symlink

Tutorial is using older Laravel and I am using Laravel 8.
Problem is he created symbolic link as:

`php artisan storage:link` and I also created as it is but he is using image as:

`<img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}">` `<===` This is not working in my case.

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->image) }}"` `<===` This is working in my case.

I want to know if I am using it in correct way?

Comment: Your way is correct. What does the guy in that tutorial has in `$post->image`?

Comment: He has this working url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/IwXdQPBEBYvn06A3QHGtiolOZJDbaJnt0qxMZhh9.png`

And I have this working url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/posts/IwXdQPBEBYvn06A3QHGtiolOZJDbaJnt0qxMZhh9.png`

Difference is `storage/`

Comment: Looking at the configuration, it is certain that the tutorial guy has done something additional. Nevertheless, you way is correct.